# Create a Recyclerview with list of Acitvty in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show a list of activity class in Recyclerview and want to move coresponding activity while click on it. I can do it java but failed to do it in Kotlin.

In Java I can declare an array of class and then iterate to go with intent.

```
Class classes[] = [ firstActivity.class, DetailActivity.class, .... So on];
Intent i = new Intent(this, classes[position]);
startActivity(i);
```

But failed to do it in Kotlin. Any Idea?

**Update**: My Activities are also kotlin file.

Comment: `::class.java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**`arrayOf`**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of.html)  for **KOTLIN**

```
  val className = arrayOf(LoginActivity::class.java,DashboardActivity::class.java)
  val i = Intent(this@CurrentActivity, className[1])
  startActivity(i);
```

From ***Java to Kotlin-***>Activity Extensions will **`::class.java`**

```
Class classes[] = [ LoginActivity::class,DashboardActivity::class.java];
Intent i = new Intent(this, classes[position]);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But my acitivites are also kotlin file not java class @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: I am testing and reply you back soon.

Comment: Solved the issue.

Comment: @InteliJ Amiya Can i get the name of Activity Class as String from array?

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin instead of this code

```
DetailActivity.class
```

You must use this

```
DetailActivity::class.java
```